# How to handle related many-to-many records in PUT method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I am having two problems with updating my entity which contains 2 many-to-many collections, here how it looks:

```
public class Media
    {
        public int MediaId { get; set; }
        public string ImdbId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public bool IsAdult { get; set; }
        public int? StartYear { get; set; }
        public int? EndYear { get; set; }
        public int? RuntimeMinutes { get; set; }
        public decimal? AvgRating { get; set; }
        public int? NumVotes { get; set; }

        #region navigation properties
        public ICollection<MediaGenre> MediaGenres { get; set; }
        public ICollection<MediaPerson> MediaPeople { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
```

Both collections look like this:

```
public class MediaGenre
    {
        public int MediaId { get; set; }
        public int GenreId { get; set; }

        #region navigation properties
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public Media Media { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
```

PUT method execution:

```
public async Task<MediaRatedWithIdDto?> UpdateMediaAsync(int id, MediaRatedDto mediaDto)
        {
            try
            {
                //Check if media by the id exists in the database
                var existingMedia = await _unitOfWork.MediaRepository.GetMediaByIdAsync(id);
                if (existingMedia == null)
                {
                    throw new BadHttpRequestException($"There is no media by the id:{id} in the database.",
                        StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest);
                }

                //update the media using automapper (I have to manually set id's cause they are forced to default after mapping)
                var imdbid = existingMedia.ImdbId;
                var mediaid = existingMedia.MediaId;
                existingMedia = _mapper.Map<Media>(mediaDto);
                existingMedia.ImdbId = imdbid;
                existingMedia.MediaId = mediaid;

                await _unitOfWork.MediaRepository.UpdateMediaAsync(existingMedia);

                //map the dbo media into the dto media
                var updatedMedia = _mapper.Map<MediaRatedWithIdDto>(existingMedia);
                return updatedMedia;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
            }

            return null;
        }
```

**First problem:** My DTO doesn't contain any Id's, and even though I ignored them in my mapping profile, those Id's that were presented in my existingMedia are set to default values, and I don't know how to fix it. Now I am simply saving the ids manually in strings and then assigning them back after mapping.

```
    CreateMap<MediaRatedDto, Media>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ImdbId, 
                    opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForMember(dest => dest.MediaId,
                    opt => opt.Ignore())
```

And the **second problem** is that it doesn't update the collections, after mapping they are changed, I can see in debug that new MediaGenres and new MediaPeople are created correctly, and assigned to the existingMedia I am trying to update, but after:

```
await _unitOfWork.MediaRepository.UpdateMediaAsync(existingMedia);

//Code of the method called above
    public async Task UpdateMediaAsync(Media media)
            {
                _context.Entry(media).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
```

The old values are kept in the database many-to-many tables, and new ones are never created, I suppose it is the default behavior and I can fix it by manually deleting the old ones and inserting the new ones, but it doesn't seem right, how can I fix it?

Comment: It's hard to understand. Can you reformulate the process in plain code?

Comment: @vernou Done, maybe it is a bit more understandable now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with mapping was caused by incorrect syntax:
old:

```
existingMedia = _mapper<Media>(mediaDto);
```

new:

```
_mapper.Map(mediaDto, existingMedia);
```

The problem with not changing collections was caused by asnotracking in the GetMediaByIdAsync, and incorrect update syntax
old:

```
return _context.Media
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(x => x.MediaGenres)
                .Include(x => x.MediaPeople)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.MediaId == id);
```

new:

```
return _context.Media
                .Include(x => x.MediaGenres)
                .Include(x => x.MediaPeople)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.MediaId == id);
```

old:

```
public async Task UpdateMediaAsync(Media media)
        {
            _context.Entry(media).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

new:

```
public async Task UpdateMediaAsync(Media media)
    {
        _context.Media.Update(media);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```